# Cannot get "Open in MyApp" to work with PNG or JPG Mail attachment in my iOS app

Tags: file-type, ios

Here are the pertinent contents of my app's info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon_72x72.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MyApp File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapp.export</string>
            <string>com.myapp.backup</string>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
            <string>public.comma-separated-values-text</string>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
            <string>public.png</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

When I try to tap and hold on a XLS, CSV, or PDF attachment in Mail, the "Open in MyApp" option shows up and everything works fine as my app delegate's openURL method is fired. However, when I tap and hold on a PNG or JPG attachment in Mail, I do not get the option to open in my app.

Is there some other setting that I need to change in order to have images open in my app? I am thoroughly confused as to why some of the content types work and some don't.

I have seen quite a bit of the Apple documentation and other SO questions and blog posts, and still have not been able to get it working, so please don't just point out similar unanswered SO questions or Apple docs.

Comment: Why have you asked this twice?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, when I look through the list of questions I have asked, it only shows up once. Did you see a similar question asked by another developer?

Answer (score 5):

You are not alone. This is an issue with the mail app in my opinion. The Photos app has the same issue. You can't choose to open a photo in the Photos app with any 3rd party app either. I can't figure out why Apple made this decision.

I suggest you file an enhancement request at bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: It works for the google drive and Houzz apps, we should be able to add this functionality to ours as well.

Comment: @zambono I have the Google Drive app on my iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.2. The Photos app does not offer the ability to open a photo in any 3rd party app for me, including Google Drive. Same with an image as an email attachment. How are you seeing this?

Comment: I have tried all the methodology provided here and other places as well, but I am still struggling to get open PNG files. I am working with iOS 7. In some places they are saying that this problem starts with ios 6. Is it true? Can't we open png files in "Open in " dialog box with ios 7?